# Strange silverlight behavior in chrome lately

Tags: javascript, silverlight, google-chrome

Lately (starting in January 2014) I have noticed that Chrome sometimes does not display Silverlight application unless your press F11 (full screen) on Ctrl+Shift+C (inspect element).

It mostly happens when you follow a link from Skype or from another page, so I will place a link here so anyone can experience this bug. It happens in roughly 50% of cases when you follow a link. Pasting a link into address bar doesn't trigger the bug for me.

Here is the link: http://www.icmpoker.com/icmizer/#default

Also hitting F11 doesn't always help. but hitting Ctrl+Shift+C helps.

So here are my questions:

1. Anyone else is experiencing this problem?
2. Is there a way to make a page "refresh" (as F11 or Ctrl+Shift+C seems to do) from javascript or using any other means?
3. Any idea on how to deal with this bug is also welcome.

Comment: Seems to work fine if you open in new window or same tab, but open in new tab is exhibiting this behavior for me: Version 32.0.1700.107 m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug of Chrome 32. It will be fixed in the next version. See https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/9QqVfMG3H4w/xlN7t5qh63sJ

The plugin object is displayed only if you load the page in the default tab of the browser. In any new tab, you must resize the window (or press F12 twice).

In the meanwhile, you can open your links in a popup window when Chrome is detected.

For instance :

```
if(/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].url = links[i].href;
        links[i].href = "javascript:return false;";
        links[i].onclick = function(e) {
            window.open(e.target.url, "_blank", "height =" + screen.height + ",width=" + screen.width).moveTo(0,0);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Good news, the bug is fixed in the latest public release (version 33.0.1750.117 m) :-)